# Multidimensional array output

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I have this array `data` which i want to be coded somewhat like `[lojas, raparacoes, valor],[nome_1, count_1, val_1],[nome_2, count_2, val_2], etc, etc...`

`lojas`, `reparacoes` and `valor` are like headers

`nome_*` comes from `$row['nome']`

`count_*` comes from `intval($row['COUNT( DISTINCT id_reparacao )'])`

`val_*` comes from `intval($row2['SUM(valor)'])`

```
$data = array(array('Lojas'), array('Reparacoes'), array('Valor'));
$qry=mysql_query ('SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT id_reparacao ) , lojas.nome, lojas.id
FROM reparacoes
INNER JOIN lojas ON lojas.id = id_loja 
GROUP BY lojas.id ');

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
        {
            $qry2=mysql_query ('SELECT SUM(valor) FROM re_servicos where id_reparacao=(select id_reparacao from reparacoes where id_loja='.$row['id'].' and estado="Fechada")');
            while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($qry2))
                {
                    $data=[$row['nome'],intval($row['COUNT( DISTINCT id_reparacao )']), intval($row2['SUM(valor)'])];   
                }
        }
```

However, with this code I'm not getting the desired output in the array, I guess the problem is the way i fill it but I don't know how to properly fill it so it gets the output I posted in the first paragraph.

PS: I don't know if it matters but for better understanding, I need this array to build a [google bar chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart?hl=pt-PT)

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code.

```
 $data = array();
$data[] = array('Lojas', 'Reparacoes', 'Valor');
$qry=mysql_query ('SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT id_reparacao ) , lojas.nome, lojas.id
FROM reparacoes
INNER JOIN lojas ON lojas.id = id_loja 
GROUP BY lojas.id ');

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry))
        {
            $qry2=mysql_query ('SELECT SUM(valor) FROM re_servicos where id_reparacao=(select id_reparacao from reparacoes where id_loja='.$row['id'].' and estado="Fechada")');
            while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($qry2))
                {
                    $data[]=array($row['nome'],intval($row['COUNT( DISTINCT id_reparacao )']), intval($row2['SUM(valor)']));   
                }
        }
```

Comment: Working perfectly, Thank you. (I'm accepting this answer as soon as possible)